# display inline without float

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have 3 tables that looks like this:
[image]
What I would like to do is have them all 3 line up in a row withou a space between each table(bottom table goes where the red square is). The problem I have is apparent, but I cannot seems to get rid of those gaps inbetween the table wihout using negative margins which I would like to avoid since I heard it's not good practice (browsers might break it). Would it also be possible to align the tables without floating them? I've tried to use a couple of these tricks but none seems to work: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Here is my css:
my main body is 901px wide so I just changed my width to 300 for each table

```
.measure_data {
    width: 299px;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Those tricks only apply to `inline-block` elements ... without `float` of course

Comment: I have my tables as `inline-blocks`

Comment: did you try setting the spacing and margin to `0` (explicitly)? sorry if this sounds dumb but I have to ask

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: funny how this stuff always shows up after I post.. I'll remove it if that answer works

Comment: I have tried margin 0

Comment: @john if your tables are dynamically generated, then create them without any whitespace between them - [example](http://jsfiddle.net/fvmyd7ch/)

Comment: This happen because of lack of space( margin/ padding creating issues). in this case you can use another parent wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

White space between elements is inevitable when using `display: inline-block;`. Try this. You need to make sure you "tie" the gaps together, like so:

```
<div>
    <p>1/3</p>
</div><!--
--><div>
    <p>1/3</p>
</div><!--
--><div>
    <p>1/3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: my tables are being dynamically generated

Comment: The only realistic way of combatting this with inline-block elements then, is to minify the output source of the tables, so that the tables are on just one line, unfortunately. This is the biggest pitfall of inline-block elements. AngularJS deals with this perfectly, and a few tempting engines such as Twig.

Answer (score 0):

You should reduce the table with 299 to 290

```
.measure_data {
    width: 290px;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here click here to see in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hv3281b/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Add position to second and third table:

```
.measure_data {
    width: 299px;
    border: solid 1px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    display: inline-block;
}
.2{
   position: absolute; 
}
.3{
   position: relative; 
}
```